# OSRM: Find place on route after some elapsed time?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, osrm

For a given start and end point of a route, I want to know at which point on the route I will be  after a certain amount of time. 
E.g. given coordinates long_start, lat_start and long_end, lat_end, and taking the route that OSRM suggests, where will the car be after 2 minutes?

Is there a simple way to do this via the OSRM HTTP-API?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the option `annotations=duration&overview=full` to the `route` service and then use the `routes[0].legs[0].annotations.durations` array to find out at which coordinate you would be after a given time.

Pseudo-code:

```
sum = 0
index = 0
durations = routes[0].legs[0].annotations.durations
while index < durations.length and sum < max_duration
   sum += durations[index]
   index++
location = decodePolyline(routes[0].geometry)[index]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As it seems, annotation objects only contain node-ids, but not long-lat values. Is there any way to obtain the longitude and latitude for a given node-id via the OSRM-API?

Comment: Yes that is what you do with the `index`: You can map it back to the route geometry.

Comment: There is still one problem. According to the OSRM [API documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#annotation-object), the annotation does not contain the duration of any turns. This means that the sum of the durations in the annotation object may be smaller than the total duration of the trip, and it's not clear when these turns happen.